# Bootstrap 3.2 jQuery in modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I want to use some jQuery in my Modals. For like form validation, but the problem is more general.

I load the content of the modals from another html-file.
In Bootstrap 3.1.x it worked with just putting the jQuery code at the end of the html file from where I get my modalcontent.

But now with Bootstrap 3.2. the jQuery doesn't work anymore in the modals.

Outside of the modals they working fine.
Even if I call the contenpage not within the modal the jQuery works.

Here is some example code showing how I call my modals:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="dir" data-target="#inputModal">Some Button</td>

<div class="modal fade" id="inputModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="inputModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the content.html for the modalcontent

```
<form name="contactdeleteform" method="post">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="moduleModalLabel">topic</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
      <select id="modules" name="modules" class="form-control select2" multiple>
         <option value="1">option 1 </option>         
      </select>          
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Back</button>
    <button type="submit" id="contactDataSubmit"  class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('.select2').select2({placeholder: "Bitte Auswahl treffen"});
</script>
```

using the [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) lib for better multiselection. For example I can't get this to work.

/edit: tried to explain the the Problem more clearly.

/edit2 : I checked the networks with the Firefox debugging tools and there is no jQuery call when I load the modal

Comment: are you using $.load() ?

Comment: no. only the defaul remote modal function of bootstrep itself

Comment: @muthan [That feature is deprecated.](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/14034)

Comment: `.modal({remote})` That's not valid JS.

Comment: oh you are rigt that's not valid. but your tip with the deprecated feature is actually helping, at least a bit and for understanding. But I don't know how I use the knowledge that i have to use the $.load() function to get the result I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that a friend of mine sugested.

When you put the id of the modalframe into the jquery it works.

```
$(#modalid #idforjqueryelemnt).function()(...
```

So in the case of my problem I change nothing much but the jquery of the content.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#inputModal .select2').select2({placeholder: "Bitte Auswahl treffen"});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if you add to your own jquery in bootstarp 3.2 use (noConflict) in your own jquery script

Example: 

<form name="contactdeleteform" method="post">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="moduleModalLabel">topic</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  Body content
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Back</button>
    <button type="submit" id="contactDataSubmit"  class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

(No Changes it's working in my sys once check your total code )

http://jsfiddle.net/suryakiran/ffqhtr35/

Comment: sadly, that doesn't do the trick. I have a feeling that he doesn't load the jquery at all.

Comment: I edited my problem with a more specific example of my problem. I don't know what u want to say with your new solution. To clarification I can load the modal. It loads fully, except the jquery. Like in my example, there is only the standart bootstrap multiselect box and not the jquery one.

Answer (score 0):

once please do your project example in (http://jsfiddle.net). i will try to solve your problems. am also beginner in bootstrap. if you do your example in jsfiddle.net am learn more from you

Comment: since it was only a matter of the right label of the jquery, and the problem was very special. I am not sure how to put that problem into jsfiddle. Also as @cvrebert stated this feature of remote loading content into modals will be deprecated. see my own answer how i solved the problem. I will write a bit more.